# Variable Assigning the file path based on arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Currently I have a Shell script that runs a whole folder setup and then pushes that file to a sever

Currently I have two arguments that decided on the what is done, But I want to make it sleeker, by only having 1 path call and have the arguments assign the end path or Have the two paths stored in variables and then depending if rc or trunk is called it uses that path ?

```
scp $Version.zip root@i-sever.com://data/folder/rcfolder/Patch_$Version.zip;
```

Hers what I currently have

```
 if [ "$1" = "rc" ]
    then
        scp $Version.zip root@i-sever.com://data/folder/rcfolder/Patch_$Version.zip;
    elif [ "$1" = "trunk" ]
    then
        scp $Version.zip root@i-sever.com:/data/folder/trunkfolder/Update_$Version.zip;
    fi
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an associative array:

```
declare -A filename=([rc]=Patch [trunk]=Update)
if [[ ${filename[$1]} ]] ; then
    scp $Version.zip root@i-sever.com:/data/folder/$1/${filename[$1]}_$Version.zip
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
upload() {
    [[ "$1" == "rc" ]] && arg="Patch" || arg="Update"
    scp "$Version.zip" "root@i-sever.com://data/folder/$1/${arg}_${Version}.zip"
}
```

Then use it as:

```
upload rc
upload trunk
```